# How I can seed a user with a quote?

Tags: magento2, database, development

I am developing a functionality where I need a user with quoted. But for development speed I want to create via command-line a single user with 2 quotes for a specific website. Is there a tool that allows me to do so?

What I want is an easy way to seed dummy data in my database so I can easily develop Observer regarding quotes?

I want the quote to have specific requirements therefore writing my own seeder will help me a lot.

Comment: Magento does not have such  tools create quotes using the command line .